# How to check if a dictionary value is equal to a variable's value

Tags: python

I'm creating a Python library for creating simple text-based games, and I need to compare an item in a dictionary's value to a variable's value.

EDIT: I have a dictionary for items that exist in a world.

```
ITEMS_IN_WORLD = {"Key": "Hotel", "Stone": "Park"}
```

I also have a variable that contains the player's current 'location'.

```
CURRENT_LOCATION = "Store"
```

What I need to do is make the program check if `CURRENT_LOCATION` is equal to one of the dictionary's values. (Hotel, Park, etc.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, improve your question, what you ever tried?

Comment: So what's stopping you from comparing the item in the dictionary to the contents of the simple variable?

Comment: If dict_name["key"]==var_name: do_something

Comment: @PM2Ring I don't know how, that's it.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque That's exactly what I need, thanks!

Comment: `variable in dictionary.values()` should do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for item, location in ITEMS_IN_WORLD.iteritems():
 if (CURRENT_LOCATION==location):
  print ("Found!")  #Or whatever you intend to do
```